# Grouping data returned from a sub query

Tags: sql

I have the following query which returns values based on the account type:

```
SELECT COALESCE(B.classdescription, 'S CORPORATION') AS "DESCRIPTION", 
       Count(*)                                      AS "NUMBEROFACCOUNTS", 
       Sum(Cast(current_cert_shares AS DECIMAL(20, 3))) 
       + Sum(Cast(current_book_shares AS DECIMAL(20, 3))) 
       + Sum(Cast(dr_curr_shares AS DECIMAL(20, 3))) AS TOTAL 
FROM   testtable1 A 
       LEFT JOIN testtable2 B 
              ON A.class_code = B.classcode 
WHERE  conumber = 00000 
       AND A.special_account_code NOT IN( 001 ) 
GROUP  BY B.classdescription, 
          A.class_code
```

The requirement is to show data only for class codes '001', '002', '003', '004', '005'. The data for rest of the class codes (006 to 010) need to be collated and shown as description "OTHER" with sum of the NUMBEROFACCOUNTS and TOTAL for class codes 006 to 010.

Following image will show the view required. No requirement to calculate the %OS value:

[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtPO6.png)

[image]

How can one achieve this view with a single query?

The total values for "Other" can be derived from this:

```
SELECT Sum(a.numberofaccounts) AS other, 
       Sum(a.total)            AS othertotal 
FROM   ( 
             SELECT    COALESCE(b.classdescription, 'S CORPORATION') AS "DESCRIPTION",
                       Count(*)                                      AS "NUMBEROFACCOUNTS",
                       Sum(Cast(current_cert_shares AS DECIMAL(20,3))) +
                       Sum(Cast(current_book_shares AS DECIMAL(20,3))) +
                       Sum(Cast(dr_curr_shares AS DECIMAL(20,3))) AS total
             FROM      accountmaster A 
             LEFT JOIN classcodes B 
             ON        a.class_code = b.classcode 
             WHERE     conumber = 11991 
             AND       a.special_account_code NOT IN(02) --and 
                       class_code NOT             IN( '042', '010', '012', '022', '011') 
             GROUP BY  b.classdescription, 
                       a.class_code ) a
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com